# :before and :after selectors on internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I have some css code that use :before and :after selectors:

```
.caption-wrap .line-3:before,
.caption-wrap .line-3:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.caption-wrap .line-3:before {
    margin: 7px 0 0 -60px;
}
.caption-wrap .line-3:after {
    margin: 7px 0 0 10px;
}
```

The slide HTML markup:

```
<li>
    <img src="images/mountains.jpg" class="parallax-bg" alt="">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container hidden-xs">
        <div class="caption-wrap">
            <p class="line-1">we are</p>
            <h1 class="line-2 dashed-shadow">
                MINIMAL</h1>
                <h4 class="line-3">Design | Develpment | Success</h4>
                <p class="line-5">
                    <a href="#">codenpixel</a>
                    <a href="#">retrograde</a>
                </p>
                <p class="line-6">2014</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

This look like this, on Chrome:
[image]

And internet explorer:
[image]

On internet explorer developers tools all this css code is strikethrough, so I suppose that is being 
ignored. Is there a way to make this css work in internet explorer?

Website [link](http://themescreators.com/t-one/).

Comment: Not without altering the HTML. You'd need to place an element either side of your `.caption-wrap`

Comment: Which version of IE? and can we see you markup?

Comment: I have this issue in all the latest versions of IE 8, 9, 10 and 11

Comment: without markup, example to reproduce issue, it is going to be hard to find a solution to fix your issue. Have you inspected the page with some code inspecting tools? are both pseudo elements displaying at the same location in IE?

Comment: I have added HTML markup and website link to the question. And no they are not on the same location, before pseudo elements seems to be out of the screen. If I change pseudo element margin it appears.

Comment: try using top:0  and left:0 as well with position absolute.

Comment: Have you spelt development wrong deliberately?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need absolute positioning for the pseudo elements. You can achieve the desired layout with `display:inline-block;` on pseudo elements :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/wxngm6vr/1/)**

*CSS :*

```
.caption-wrap .line-3:before,
.caption-wrap .line-3:after {
    content: " ";
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    margin: 7px 10px 0;
}
```

*Tested on IE 11 but this should work on [all versions supporting pseudo elements](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) (IE8 +)*