# CSS pseudo elements in select tag options in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-select

I'm trying to add some CSS `::before` content to the `<option>` tags of a `<select multiple>` depending on if the option is selected or not.

The below is currently working fine in Chrome & FF, but I'm having issues in IE11.

```css
select > option::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
}
select > option:checked::before {
  content: "SELECTED: ";
}
select > option:not(:checked)::before {
  content: "excluded: " ;
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
  <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
  <option value="4" selected="selected">4</option>
  <option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
</select>
```

I've read other SO posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36774788/after-before-pseudo-elements-in-ie11), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076744/why-is-ie-11-not-rendering-after-element-showing-css-as-crossed-out-in-dev-too), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875232/ie-crossing-out-pseudo-element-css), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801642/before-and-after-selectors-on-internet-explorer)) about pseudo elements in IE and most seem to point to setting some sort of `position` or `display` attribute which I've tried.

Is this happening as `<option>` tags shouldn't contain child elements?

Comment: Great Question.  I'll bounty this in 48 hours.  I'm trying to do the same thing in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48776016/1366033) I just answered It would appear though that this is not possible in IE as browsers have historically been a relatively opinionated on rendering `select` elements and their contents, but maybe there is some workaround

Comment: I don't think pseudo element inside of an option is valid https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410679/using-before-with-option-element-in-a-drop-down-list

Comment: We can't create what you desire in `IE` because it doesn't allow anything other than `<option>` tag inside a `<select>` box. So if you desire we can create a `<select>` box style with *radio buttons* and get the value what you desire from it. So if you want I can create one for you. Other than that only `script` can save you

Comment: Are you open to a JS solution?

Comment: @Huangism I was afraid that was the case.

Comment: @JonathanChaplin Ideally I wanted a pure CSS one, but that doesn't look like it'll be possible.  Will probably have to use JS and have an `.onchange` function that updates the content of the `<option>` tags

Answer (score 1):

> ***First Lets get one thing straight*** we can't create what you desire in **IE** because it doesn't allow anything other than `<option>`,`<optgroup>` tags inside
>   a `<select>` box.

This is much of a **workaround** I can get using **`CSS`** only method in my opinion. If you prefer script there are plenty alternatives even [select2](https://select2.org/) is one of the most used plugin for this type of customizations.

> I Have used [type="checkbox"] for attain this result

***jQuery is only being used to show the value.***

```js
var multyVal = [];
$('.multiple input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var Tval = $(this).val();
    multyVal.push(Tval);
  }
});

console.log($('select').val(), multyVal);
```

```css
select>option::before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10em;
}

select>option:checked::before {
  content: "SELECTED: ";
}

select>option:not(:checked)::before {
  content: "excluded: ";
}

.multiple {
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: #d4d4d4;
  width: 10em;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.multiple [type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.multiple label {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: right;
  background: #fff;
}

.multiple label::before {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-family: arial, san-sarif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

.multiple [type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  content: "SELECTED: ";
}

.multiple [type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
}

.multiple [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)+label::before {
  content: "excluded: ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select multiple>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
  <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
  <option value="4" >4</option>
  <option value="5" >5</option>
</select>


<div class="multiple">
  <input type="checkbox" name="multiple" value="1" id="rad1" checked="checked">
  <label for="rad1">1</label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="multiple" value="2" id="rad2" checked="checked">
  <label for="rad2">2</label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="multiple" value="3" id="rad3" checked="checked">
  <label for="rad3">3</label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="multiple" value="4" id="rad4">
  <label for="rad4">4</label>

  <input type="checkbox" name="multiple" value="5" id="rad5">
  <label for="rad5">5</label>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jithinrajpr7/u94v0L38/) in case you want one.

Hoping this would come handy for you guys...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I thought that would be the case; that only `<option>` tags inside `<select>` box.

Unfortunately stuck with a `<select multiple>` box.

Comment: @Rob it's k, glad I could be of some assistance. your `js` solution works well too.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally I was looking for a pure CSS solution but as per the comments and @weBer

The `<select>` tag can only contain:

> [Zero or more `<option>`, `<optgroup>`, and script-supporting elements.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/sec-forms.html#the-select-element)

Therefore I will probably end up using a JavaScript solution like the below.

```js
document.getElementById("multiSelect").onchange = function() {

  var opts = this.getElementsByTagName("option");

  for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {

    if (opts[i].selected === true) {
      opts[i].innerHTML = "SELECTED: " + opts[i].value;
    } else {
      opts[i].innerHTML = "excluded: " + opts[i].value;
    }

  }
};
```

```css
select {
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<select id="multiSelect" multiple>
    <option value="1">excluded: 1</option>
    <option value="2">excluded: 2</option>
    <option value="3">excluded: 3</option>
    <option value="4">excluded: 4</option>
    <option value="5">excluded: 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I actually haven't used `INCLUDED` and `excluded` text strings actually used the unicode characters for ballot box (with and without checks) as per @KyleMit [answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48776016/2053770).